# JavaScript date/time pattern %t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm} - RegExp to read pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, datetime, formatting

Below is Node.js module with function `format()` that is actually taken from Node.js 'util' module [`util.format(format, [...])`](http://www.nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format)

date.js adds format() function to Date prototype.

How to make RegExpression so that it can extract time format pattern after the placeholder?

```
// from Node.js util module
util = require ('util');
inspect = util.inspect;
require('./date.js'); // adds .format to Date prototype

var formatRegExp = /%[sdjt%]/g; //+ t
exports.format = function(f) {
  if (typeof f !== 'string') {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      objects.push(inspect(arguments[i]));
    }
    return objects.join(' ');
  }

  var i = 1;
  var args = arguments;
  var len = args.length;
  var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
    if (x === '%%') return '%';
    if (i >= len) return x;
    switch (x) {
      case '%s': return String(args[i++]);
      case '%d': return Number(args[i++]);
      case '%j': return JSON.stringify(args[i++]);
      // added time = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s');
      case '%t': return args[i++].format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); //+ added line
      default:
        return x;
    }
  });
  for (var x = args[i]; i < len; x = args[++i]) {
    if (x === null || typeof x !== 'object') {
      str += ' ' + x;
    } else {
      str += ' ' + inspect(x);
    }
  }
  return str;
};
```

Maybe there is other solution to support exact format usage with `%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}`

`console.log( formatutil.format('log-%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log', curtime ) );`

UPDATE:

**that is what RegExp could catch '%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}' in 'log-%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log'**

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for a different lib, there is http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I have already looked at momentjs. Date.format() may also be implemented with it. My question is what RegExp could catch '%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}' in 'log-%t{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log'